# How to find the latest git issue number on github using python?

Tags: python, git, github, request, github-api

I need to find the latest git issue number for a repository using python for all users rather than an authenticated user.
Is there any way i could do this? either through the API or any library?
I looked at the github docs and from my understanding it is not possible to list issues for all users but only authenticated users.
I looked at pygithub where all i could find was how to create an issue through the library

Comment: Of cause you will have to authenticate to see issues that are access restricted and it might not even be guaranteed that you will ever see all. What do you need the number for?

Comment: I have access to view all issues.

Comment: You can read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02467). In this paper, the authors mention the implementation of SZZ that use `git` command to identify the issue number. Just check it to help.

Comment: @Yusufsn Github issues are not versioned in main git repository.

Comment: I'm going to echo a question in Klaus' comment: Why do you want this? As soon as you get that answer it could be out of date, e.g. if a user creates an issue just as you look up the most recent one. This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kevin Vizalil

You can use the Github API's to get the list of issues or single issue

please check `https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues`

edit:

e.g. `https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?sort=created&direction=desc`